# Rails won't compile assets, but shows the compile in the log, rake assets:precompile not generating files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, precompile

When I run `rake assets:precompile` it shows in the logs that it compiles `plugin.js` and `knockout`, however, those files are not in `public/assets`. What is wrong?

#### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree .
```

Searching for the files:

```
[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$ find public/assets -name plugin.js
[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$ find public/assets -name knock\*

[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$ grep plugin.js log/production.log
Compiled ckeditor/plugins/youtube/plugin.js  (0ms)  (pid 32556)
Compiled ckeditor/plugins/youtube/plugin.js  (0ms)  (pid 32556)
[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$ grep knockout log/production.log
Compiled knockout-3.1.0.js  (0ms)  (pid 32556)
Compiled knockout-3.1.0.js  (0ms)  (pid 32556)

[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$ grep plugin.js public/assets/manifest.yml
[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$ grep knockout public/assets/manifest.yml
[vagrant@localhost BK-Development]$
```

These are in my `production.rb`. Should not be relevant.

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.modal.js bootstrap.modal.css application/_helper_classes.css 
bootstrap-datepicker.js bootstrap-datepicker.css books_admin.js categories.js posts.js )
```

Rails 3.2.14

Comment: Did you run it with `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: Yes. It adds that automatically: `$ rake assets:precompile`
`/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@bk_development/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`

Answer (score 0):

I explicitly added `knockout-3.1.0.js` and `plugin.js` to `config.assets.precompile` and that generated the files in `public/assets`. I still don't know why it would generate all the other JS files except those.

Comment: Please accept your own answer. You need that because even though Rails compiles those files, unless you add them to your `precompile` array, they are meant to be used with sprockets i.e. inside your `application.js`. You can check that `application.js` indeed is loading it.

Comment: They are not in `application.js` either! I looked in the file and searched for the comment at the top of `knockout.js` and `plugin.js`. All the other files were inside `application.js` but not those two. For example, there is a `books.js` in the `javascripts` directory, and it was compiled into its own file under `public/assets`, and it was also in `manifest.yml`, and it was included in `application.js`, but for some reason, `knockout.js` and `plugin.js` were not compiled as files or even in `application.js`. The top comment in `knockout.js` is `// Knockout JavaScript library v3.1.0`.